# Initializer for frame for MKAnnotationView

Tags: ios, swift, mkannotationview

The following code returns a couple of compiler errors:

```
override init(frame: CGRect) { //Initializer does not override a designated initializer from its superclass
    super.init(frame: frame) //Must call a designated initializer of the superclass 'MKAnnotationView'
}
```

After doing some research I amended the above init method to this:

```
init() {
    super.init(frame: CGRect)
}
```

But then  I get the error "Cannot convert value of type 'CGRect.Type' to expected argument type 'CGRect'

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to create your `MKAnnotationView` object with a `frame` argument, you can try to init it with the snippet below, note that you need to call `super` init function and pass `CGRectZero` as a value for the `frame` argument:

```
init() {
    super.init(frame: CGRectZero)
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```